# PowerShell script to open four different Windows Explorer paths and position each window

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-ise

I am trying to write a script that opens up Windows Explorer four times (each window with a different path) and positions each window in a corner of the screen so that they cover equal areas. The script will be used on machines with different screen resolutions so ideally it should be based on window size, but this isn't an absolute must, just as long as they're not overlapping (I think the min screen resolution it will be used on is 1366x768).

I am new to PowerShell scripting so I've managed to get *some* things working, I'm just struggling to fit it all together. I was able to get four separate Windows Explorer windows to open where I wanted:

```
ii $path1
ii $path2
ii $path3
ii $path4
```

I was also able to open *Internet Explorer* to a set size using `-ComObject`:

```
$IE = New-Object -ComObject Internetexplorer.application

$IE.Left = 0
$IE.Width = 500
$IE.Top = 0
$IE.Height = 500

$IE.Navigate($URL)

$IE.Visible = $True
```

I can't get it to work with Windows Explorer though. I've also managed to get the resolution for the monitor:

```
$monitor = Get-Wmiobject Win32_Videocontroller
$monitor.CurrentHorizontalResolution
$monitor.CurrentVerticalResolution
```

Unfortunately this provides 2 resolutions because I have two monitors, and I'm not sure how to extract the resolution for just one of them. Additionally, I don't know what that would mean if the script was run on a machine with only one monitor.

So with what I currently have, I would specifically like to know:

1. How to open my Windows Explorer windows to a certain size and position as I have done with IE (doesn't have to be with `ii` either, anything that works)
2. How to extract a single value for monitor resolution that I can do some maths with to get the optimum sizing.

Thanks.

---

**EDIT:** I have found a quick-fix but it's not quite there. By examining the commands available to me with the shell, and came up with this:

```
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

ii $path1
ii $path2
ii $path3
ii $path4

$Shell.TileHorizontally()
```

This should work, because it's likely that the user will have only these four windows open and nothing else. Unfortunately, `TileHorizontally()`works on all open windows, but it looks like the `ii` commands don't execute fast enough or something, because they don't tile when the script is run. They do if you run it a second time, once the script is already open. I thought that the `-Wait` option would help me here, but it doesn't seem to work with `ii`. Anyone see a solution to this?

**EDIT 2:** My current code, using `Set-Window` with doc comments removed:

```
Function Set-Window {
    [OutputType('System.Automation.WindowInfo')]
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        $ProcessId,
        [int]$X,
        [int]$Y,
        [int]$Width,
        [int]$Height,
        [switch]$Passthru
    )
    Begin {
        Try{
            [void][Window]
        } Catch {
        Add-Type @"
              using System;
              using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
              public class Window {
                [DllImport("user32.dll")]
                [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
                public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

                [DllImport("User32.dll")]
                public extern static bool MoveWindow(IntPtr handle, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool redraw);
              }
              public struct RECT
              {
                public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
                public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
                public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
                public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
              }
"@
        }
    }
    Process {
        $Rectangle = New-Object RECT
        $Handle = (Get-Process -Id $ProcessId).MainWindowHandle
        $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
        If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Width')) {            
            $Width = $Rectangle.Right - $Rectangle.Left            
        }
        If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Height')) {
            $Height = $Rectangle.Bottom - $Rectangle.Top
        }
        If ($Return) {
            $Return = [Window]::MoveWindow($Handle, $x, $y, $Width, $Height,$True)
        }
        If ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Passthru')) {
            $Rectangle = New-Object RECT
            $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
            If ($Return) {
                $Height = $Rectangle.Bottom - $Rectangle.Top
                $Width = $Rectangle.Right - $Rectangle.Left
                $Size = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size -ArgumentList $Width, $Height
                $TopLeft = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates -ArgumentList $Rectangle.Left, $Rectangle.Top
                $BottomRight = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates -ArgumentList $Rectangle.Right, $Rectangle.Bottom
                If ($Rectangle.Top -lt 0 -AND $Rectangle.Left -lt 0) {
                    Write-Warning "Window is minimized! Coordinates will not be accurate."
                }
                $Object = [pscustomobject]@{
                    Id = $ProcessId
                    Size = $Size
                    TopLeft = $TopLeft
                    BottomRight = $BottomRight
                }
                $Object.PSTypeNames.insert(0,'System.Automation.WindowInfo')
                $Object            
            }
        }
    }
}


Get-Process -Id (Start-Process -FilePath C:\windows\explorer.exe -ArgumentList "." -Wait -Passthru).Id | Set-Window -X 500 -Y 500 -Height 500 -Width 500 -Passthru
```

Comment: Check out the [WASP](https://wasp.codeplex.com/) module...

Comment: It looks like it would solve the problem, but as the script will be distributed across multiple machines, I'd rather not have to install any extra dependencies. Unless there's a really simple way to do that from within the script?

Comment: Here's [another one](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Set-the-position-and-size-54853527) for easier Integration...

Comment: Thanks, that's much nicer. I can get it to work with notepad but not the file explorer.  As a test I did ```Get-Process notepad | Set-Window -X 500 -Y 500 -Width 500 -Height 500 -Passthru``` which works great but doesn't do anything with ```Get-Process explorer```.

Comment: You could add`$shell.MinimizeAll()`, open your windows and tile them and do a `$shell.UndoMinimizeAll()` after that.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I'm afraid that doesn't help - now the tile does not even work on a second try.

Comment: Instead of using `ii`, you could try using `Start-Process -FilePath C:\windows\explorer.exe -ArgumentList <folder> -wait`. For testing purposes, I would throw a `start-sleep 5` after each line to verify if it's a timing issue you are having.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers yep, definitely a timing issue. Even just putting a sleep after the last process was started ensured that they were all "ready" when the tile command was called. Now it's *almost* there, except the tile is behaving a bit strange and leaving a blank space for an extra window which doesn't exist. Could be picking up something else I'm running maybe?

Comment: To be clear, using `Start-Process -Wait` without a `Start-Sleep` is still not working?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers no, sorry, ```-Wait``` is now working with the full ```Start-Process``` command, it just wasn't working with ```ii```. It's quite slow though: each window takes about a second to load up. Ideally I'd love to be able to get that ```Set-Window``` function working with the file explorer, but its just not playing nice.

Comment: What exactly was the problem with `Set-Window`?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers it works fine with notepad (```Get-Process notepad | Set-Window <params>```) but trying to call it on ```Get-Process explorer``` I get errors concerning converting objects: ```"Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type 
"System.IntPtr"."``` Could it be because there's multiple instances of explorer?

Comment: Yes, exactly that but since you are now using `Start-Process`, you can get the pid and pass that to `Set-Window`. Something like `Get-Process (Start-Process -Wait -PassThru).Id | Set-Window`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers when I try this the console complains that it cannot find a process with that name (and then quotes the ID)

Comment: The `Set-Window` expects a name. I assume you could change that to check for the pid.

Comment: It's actually ```Get-Process``` which is throwing the exception. I've attempted to change it to ```Get-Process -ID ...``` and the error makes a little more sense (it is actually looking for an ID rather than a name) but I don't believe it ever reaches ```Set-Window``` because it can't find the process by its ID.

Comment: True enough, the ID it prints as "Cannot be found" is not in the list when I put ```tasklist /svc```, so somehow it is looking for a task that simply hasn't been created - where could it be getting that ID from?

Comment: I tried writing it out with a known 'explorer' PID and it is giving me the same error of not being able to convert an object to an int, so something is still going wrong.

Comment: This works for me `Get-Process -Id (Start-Process notepad -PassThru).Id` ?!

Comment: So does this `Get-Process -Id (Start-Process c:\windows\explorer -ArgumentList "c:\" -PassThru).Id`

Comment: Ug. Yeah you're right, I started a new .ps1 file and started again, those commands were working fine. It was whenever I tried to add the ```Set-Window``` function to the mix, everything fell apart. I think the function itself is somehow broken? With explorer it breaks, relating to IntPtrs and objects again, and with notepad (using the same ```-Id``` system, which throws no exceptions) it straight up does nothing. At this point the closest I've got is tiling, and it looks like I'm stuck with it.

Comment: The `Set-Window` seems to expect a name, not an Id. I haven't looked at it closely but perhaps that code can be changed to accept a pid.

Comment: Just looked at it and changing this `$Handle = (Get-Process -Name $ProcessName).MainWindowHandle` to this `$Handle = (Get-Process -Id $ProcessName).MainWindowHandle` might be all it takes *(for testing purposes. For a final solution, I'd change ProcessName to ProcessId also)*

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Okay, so I tried this. Initially I was getting **Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Id' because it is null** so I added the ```-Wait``` parameter to the ```Start-Process``` function. Then I got **Cannot find a process with the process identifier 6180** (or whatever pid it's looking for.) Finding this behavior very strange, but true enough I don't see the pid on the tasklist.

Comment: Can you post the code you are trying? For all intents and purposes, it works on my end.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers please see my edited post. For me this is currently returning the ```Cannot find process identifier``` error.

Comment: You missed changing `$ProcessName` to `$ProcessId` in the parameter section.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Yes I missed one in the ```params``` definition. Now fixed, still the same error about not being able to find the process identifier.

Comment: mmm, it took a procmon session to figure out what was going on and I only have bad news. Powershell creates an Explorer process allright and that id *is* valid but it's a transient process. Apparently, the newly created Explorer process communicaties with the shell *(also explorer.exe)*, the shell opens the folder and the Explorer process quits. There's no link to follow on what process eventually opens the folder *(digging in COM perhaps there is, but that's beyond me)*. So basically, that leaves you with enumerating all windows to find the window you've just opened and work from there.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers thanks for all your help. I've ported my progress over to a C# console application because it seemed easier to work with, and so far it's been going well.

Comment: No problem but what do you do differently using the c# console? I would assume that starting the process through the shell would have the same problem of it being transient?!

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers true, but I am generally more comfortable with C# and have been able to produce a workaround quite effortlessly: as soon as I create a new window, I just get the foreground window and manipulate that. It's not a perfect solution, but even if I end up enumerating all the windows to make it more robust I'd rather do that with C# than PowerShell scripting, which I'm not very comfortable with and find quite tiresome.

Comment: I know having had problems with it too (still do many times) but it's so powerfull as go-to tool for some quick troubleshooting. It includes much of what we have on linux system out of the box. For your usecase, the argument could be made that it's not the right tool for the job but don't give up on Powershell. You'll reach a point where it's your first go-to tool too ;)

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers oh definitely, I recognise PowerShell's potential and have exploited it in the past (and plan to in the future) but like you said I feel that it's maybe not the right tool for this particular job, and C# has proven to be a reliable old friend. But I've by no means given up n PowerShell, and will always keep it in mind for whenever I am building myself tools. Maybe once I've gained a little experience with scripting I'll come back to this problem and attempt it again in PowerShell, but for now I am happy to take what I've learned and move on for a while.